# SQL Recursive query over same table

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am new in SQL and I am trying to do a recursive query over the same table to find the brokers of the "master brokers"
I have a table that looks like this (it can grow to any amount of rows and deepness)

[image]

So I need a result like this:

master_id => broker_id

[image]

I have checked about how to do it and I got:

```
WITH admin_has_master_brokers
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT master_broker_id, admin_id
        FROM admin_has_master_brokers
            
    UNION ALL
    /*I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO DO THIS SECTION*/
    SELECT    
        master_broker_id, admin_id
    FROM admin_has_master_brokers
)
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    admin_has_master_brokers
ORDER BY master_broker_id ASC
```

But I can not understand how to do the recursive part to only get the results I need because I am getting this:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by: "I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO DO THIS SECTION"? What result are you getting from the query compared to your expectation? Is it not the same?

Comment: @AlexanderFalk hey mate I have added the result I am getting

Comment: Add  GROUP BY master_broker_id.

Comment: @Grumpy no, the results get reduced... did not work

Comment: What MySQL version?

Comment: @FaNo_FN Server version: 10.4.13-MariaDB

Comment: Well then, [Serg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68389675/10910692) is only missing `RECURSIVE` word on the query but other that that, it's should return the result you're looking for. [Refer this fiddle for Serg's answer with and without the RECURSIVE word](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=3d75c42df3b0360fe2c05f531f1d26d3)

Comment: @FaNo_FN I am lost in the part of CREATE TABLE... according to this example I need to bring up another table but can not figure out which table in my database it should be

Comment: @FaNo_FN oh nooooo... figure it out... sorry dumb comment above... I was getting messed up because actually admin_has_master_brokers is a table on my DB.... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Povided original table is `Mytable` the query lists all desendants of every master_broker_id.

```
WITH RECURSIVE admin_has_master_brokers
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT master_broker_id master, master_broker_id, admin_id
    FROM mytable
       
    UNION ALL

    SELECT a.master,  
        m.master_broker_id, m.admin_id
    FROM admin_has_master_brokers a
    JOIN mytable m ON m.master_broker_id = a.admin_id
)
SELECT DISTINCT master, admin_id    
FROM 
    admin_has_master_brokers
ORDER BY master, admin_id
```

Comment: Nice, but the query is missing the word [RECURSIVE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f91bf930aef47d410858f60dbf045fa2)

Comment: @FaNo_FN, thank you. Missed mariadb tag, corrected.