# Recursive SQL and adding the criterion in the output

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion

Learning SQL, and was given an assignment to use a single table of students and show the ones that are roommates, selecting by last name.  And then the output should be the selected last name ("smith"), and that student's home address, and then the roommate's name and the roommate's home address.

I found this post here to be quite helpful for setting up my recursion:
[SQL Recursive query over same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68389090/sql-recursive-query-over-same-table)

My problem is figuring out how to get that "static" information, the selected starting person's name and address, into the output.

Data table is titled college (I am ignoring the quotes that should be on the strings...)

| StuID | lastName | firstName | homeAdd | dormRoom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Johnson | John | 237 Maple St | b101 |
| 2 | Smith | Linda | 345 Juniper St | b101 |
| 3 | Levi | Grant | 789 SE 54th St | a304 |
| 4 | Sousa | Susi | 1024 NE 76th Pl | b101 |

Here is the code:

```
WITH RECURSIVE roommates AS
(SELECT lastName, firstName, homeAdd, dormRoom
FROM college WHERE lastName = 'Smith'
UNION
SELECT c.lastName, c.firstName, c.homeAdd, c.dormRoom
FROM roommates r
JOIN college c ON c.dormRoom = r.dormRoom
)
SELECT firstName || ' ' || lastName AS Roommate, homeAdd, dormRoom
FROM roommates
```

[image: Here is the output I'm getting, pretty much what I would expect]

The problem is that I need each line to be basically:

```
Smith     345 Juniper St     John Johnson 237 Maple St
Smith     345 Juniper St     Susi Sousa   1024 NE 76th Pl
```

Thoughts?

Comment: And I apologize that I can't seem to get the code to format correctly... it looked fine when I entered it, but now it's all strung together.

Comment: There is no need for recursion - justa simple `SELF JOIN`.